# Marshmallow nesting post_load object creation

Tags: python, flash, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm working on an API that handles nested data structures. When trying to use marshmallow i'm having trouble coming up with a solution to creating nested model instances with references to their parent instance. Marshmallow's post_load operates from the child to the parent in that order instead of parent to child. Is there a way to reverse this? I'd like to start with serializing the parent and pass it to the children as context.

```
var_test = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "dad a",
    "children_a": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "child 1 - 2",
            "grand_children_a": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "child 1 - 2",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "child 2 - 2",
        }
    ]
}

class ParentA(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    name = fields.String()
    children_a = fields.Nested('ChildrenA', many=True)
    @post_load()
    def pl_handler(self, data):
        # create Parent A
        return data

class ChildrenA(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    name = fields.String()
    grand_children_a = fields.Nested('GrandchildrenA', many=True)
    @post_load()
    def pl_handler(self, data):
        # create child of Parent A
        return data

class GrandchildrenA(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    name = fields.String()
    @post_load()
    def pl_handler(self, data):
        # create child of ChildrenA
        return "grand child string"

var_s = ParentA()
var_s.load(var_test)
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I still used marshmallow for validation serialization/deserialization but utilizing chained post_load isn't a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you don't need post_load, as there is not class which is going to deserialize from this schema, so just remove it, it should work.
If you plan to dserialize and hold it to any class, you need to return in post_load decorator, for example :

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, INCLUDE, post_load

class Author:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, description, author):
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.author = author

class AuthorSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    age = fields.Int()

    @post_load
    def load_author(self, data, **kwargs):
        return Author(**data)


class BookSchema(Schema):
    title = fields.Str()
    description = fields.Str()
    author = fields.Nested(AuthorSchema)

    @post_load
    def load_book(self, data, **kwargs):
        return Book(**data)





data = {
    "title": "Test Book",
    "description": "A book Test",
    "author": {"name": "Vivek", "age": 35},
}


book = BookSchema(unknown=INCLUDE).load(data )
print(book)
print(book.author)
print(book.author.name)
```

Comment: The code example from the original question is a bit off. This unfortunately does not solve the problem. The original question tries to solve the issue that marshmallow post load starts at the bottom/children when using nested serializers and works its way up. When working with nested rest structures, you'd start saving at the top though and work your way down to children to build relationships. It's very possible, but using just post_load on it's own doesn't quite work.